# MySQL Start on Mac Keeps Failing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to start MySQL on Mac. It was able to run. However, after being turned off in "System Preferences" and rebooting, It cannot start (no matter starting in Command line or System Preferences). According to `ps aux | grep mysql`, the MySQL REPEATEDLY tried to start after failing with different PIDs.

Below is the log in the `/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err`

```
2019-07-16T15:47:40.047291Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 2062
2019-07-16T15:47:40.059057Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2019-07-16T15:47:41.217428Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2019-07-16T15:47:41.228210Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2019-07-16T15:47:41.238163Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-07-16T15:47:41.256726Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.13'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-07-16T15:47:41.465163Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011300] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Setup of socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' failed, lock file is empty'
2019-07-16T15:47:41.498381Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2019-07-16T15:47:42.239927Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3289:for_table || ref_table thread 123145521102848
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
15:47:42 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 67867 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fc63a03d200
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 70000d0a7e20 thread_stack 0x46000
0   mysqld                              0x00000001088a9d4c my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char*, unsigned long) + 60
1   mysqld                              0x0000000107cd7456 handle_fatal_signal + 678
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff51e4df5a _sigtramp + 26
3   ???                                 0x000000010d0f6558 0x0 + 4514080088
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff51beb1ae abort + 127
5   mysqld                              0x0000000108c52e99 ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long) + 329
6   mysqld                              0x00000001089f111b dict_foreign_add_to_cache(dict_foreign_t*, char const**, bool, bool, dict_err_ignore_t) + 1707
7   mysqld                              0x0000000108a0a867 dd_table_load_fk_from_dd(dict_table_t*, dd::Table const*, char const**, dict_err_ignore_t, bool) + 1543
8   mysqld                              0x0000000108a10aa3 dict_table_t* dd_open_table_one<dd::Table>(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, TABLE const*, char const*, dd::Table const*, THD*, std::__1::deque<char const*, ut_allocator<char const*> >&) + 8403
9   mysqld                              0x0000000108a01315 dd_table_open_on_dd_obj(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, dd::Table const&, dd::Partition const*, char const*, dict_table_t*&, THD*) + 2213
10  mysqld                              0x0000000108a02595 dd_table_open_on_id_low(THD*, MDL_ticket**, unsigned long long) + 1717
11  mysqld                              0x0000000108a01d1b dd_table_open_on_id(unsigned long long, THD*, MDL_ticket**, bool, bool) + 2043
12  mysqld                              0x0000000108be3a71 row_purge_step(que_thr_t*) + 753
13  mysqld                              0x0000000108ba67f7 que_run_threads(que_thr_t*) + 679
14  mysqld                              0x0000000108c0e56c srv_worker_thread() + 668
15  mysqld                              0x0000000108ae6ce6 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, Runnable, void (*)()> >(void*) + 118
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51e57661 _pthread_body + 340
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51e5750d _pthread_body + 0
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51e56bf9 thread_start + 13

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: Could you post your complete mycnf (or my.ini)? How much RAM is on your MAC?